# Using a custom class loader to load Java runtime and API classes

Tags: java, classloader

Why is it advisable to load the Java Runtime classes and API classes using the default system class loader in Java? What happens if we load them using our custom class loader?

Comment: People, down votes without comments don't help anyone.  You should at least explain why you didn't like the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the criterias for `instanceof` to be true, is that the two classes must be loaded by the same classloader.  This goes for class casting too.

This would mean that instances of e.g. `String` created by *your* class loader would not be compatible with the `String` created by the system class loader.  Are not instances of and cannot be cast to.

You probably do not want that.